# android webview get initial cooke

Tags: android

i need to login in an https page with used credentials.But my problem is that i am not able to get the cookie from the initial request.i am using an webview.Bascically i first need to get the cookie from an http request and then sent an https request with that cookie and user credentials.

Following is my OnCreate() method

```
 CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this); 
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
if (cookie != null) {
    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
    String cookieString = cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue() + "; domain=" + cookie.getDomain() ;
    cookieManager.setCookie(cookie.getDomain(), cookieString);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
}  

WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.loadUrl("www.xyz.com");

webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

and MyWebViewClient

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

    @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           view.loadUrl(url);
           return true;
       }   
   } 
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

    };

       return null;
    }
```

i am calling https link by this way

```
       HttpClient hc;
    HttpGet get = null;
    HttpResponse httpResponseData = null;
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

    final List<BasicNameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass));
    hc = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    String URL = "https://xyz.com";
    final UrlEncodedFormEntity p_entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);
    URL += p_entity;
    get = new HttpGet(URL);
    httpResponseData = hc.execute(get);
    if(httpResponseData != null){

    }
```

How should i first get cookie and attach it with this request.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the cookie store from the webview connection, and reuse it on your https connection.

```
CookieStore cs = cookieManager.getCookieStore();
hc.setCookieStore(cs);
```

see documentation here [http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html#setCookieStore(org.apache.http.client.CookieStore)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html#setCookieStore%28org.apache.http.client.CookieStore%29)

Comment: CookieManager does not have getCookieStore() method

Answer (score 0):

Actually cookies are not single value. For a particular url u can get more than one cookie value. So you must get those cookie values inside a for loop., Example

```
 List<Cookie> cookies = ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).getCookieStore().getCookies();
                if (!cookies.isEmpty()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                Cookie cookie1 = cookies.get(i);}
               // Log.e("", "Cookie-->"+cookie1);
                }
```

I think this will help you.